# Laravel form model binding and html input fields

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am using Form Model Binding in Laravel for my update views in order to achieve the priority
1. Session Flash Data (Old Input)
2. Explicitly Passed Value
3. Model Attribute Data

```
{{ Form::model($model, array('url' => $route.'/update/'.$model->id)) }}
{{ Form::label('price', trans_choice('app.price', 1), array('id' => 'price_label')) }}
{{ Form::text('price', null, array('id' => 'price')) }}
```

This works fine but I would like to do the same without using the blade notation for input fiels, that is I would like to replace

```
{{ Form::text('price', null, array('id' => 'price')) }}
```

with

```
<input type="text" name="price" id="price" value="">
```

but still get the above-mentioned priority, is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use this:

```
<input id="price" name="price" type="text" value="{{{ Form::getValueAttribute('price', null) }}}">
```

This is the function called by Form::text to replace the value.

Laravel 4 `Form::getValueAttribute` function:

```
/**
 * Get the value that should be assigned to the field.
 *
 * @param  string  $name
 * @param  string  $value
 * @return string
 */
public function getValueAttribute($name, $value = null)
{
    if (is_null($name)) return $value;

    if ( ! is_null($this->old($name)))
    {
        return $this->old($name);
    }

    if ( ! is_null($value)) return $value;

    if (isset($this->model))
    {
        return $this->getModelValueAttribute($name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but this will actually overwrite the model's default value

Comment: It will not overwrite the model's default value... it is actually the function used by the model to set a value.